# testing django forms with pytest failing

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, forms, unit-testing

I am not sure why the assertion below is failing.

Can someone please give me a feedback, I am new to pytest with django.

## test.forms

```
@pytest.fixture
def product():
    month = Month.objects.create(name="november", slug="november")

    user = User.objects.create(username="james", password="password")

    obj = Product.objects.create(
                                user=user,
                                name="broom",
                                price=19.99,
                                quantity=1,
                                month=month,
    )

    
    data = {
        'user':user,
        'name':obj.name,
        'price':obj.price,
        'quantity':obj.quantity,
        'month':month
    }

    form = ProductForm(data=data)
    yield form

def test_product_form_with_data(product):
    assert True is not None
    assert True == product.is_valid()
```

Below is what is am getting from the terminal.

Traceback error.

```
_______________________________________________________________________________________ test_product_form_with_data ________________________________________________________________________________________

product = <ProductForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(name;price;quantity;month)>

    def test_product_form_with_data(product):
        assert True is not None
>       assert True == product.is_valid()
E       assert True == False
E         -True
E         +False

tests/test_forms.py:42: AssertionError
```

## models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    month = models.ForeignKey(Month, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='months')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='users')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30, db_index=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)  
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

## forms.py

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
                'name', 
                'price', 
                'quantity',
                'month',
    ]
```

I would really appreciate a feedback to help me understand what I am doing wrong trying to test this form with data while using fixture.

Comment: Please share the code for `ProductForm`. Also, an unrelated note: you don't need to call `save()`, the `create` method already saves the object for you.

Comment: @bug i just updated the forms.py

Comment: Sorry but since it's a ModelForm, you also need to share `Product` :)

Comment: @bug i have updated it above

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `month` is a `ForeignKey` so you need to pass the object ID in `data`, something like this:

```py
data = {
    'user':user,
    'name':obj.name,
    'price':obj.price,
    'quantity':obj.quantity,
    'month':month.pk,
}
```

You would have the same problem with `user` but actually `user` is not in the list of fields handled by your form (look at `ProductForm.Meta.fields`), so it will be ignored. You can decide to either removed it from data or add it to `fields`.